# How to auto-populate the corresponding field based on user input

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form, or rather a few forms but the concept should be similar, where I need to take the user input value from one field and auto populate the corresponding fields.  For example, in order to multiply a matrix, the rows of matrix A must equal the Columns of matrix B.

So, my form:

```
<?php
    case 'Multiply':
         echo "<p>Matrix Multiplication requires Matrix B to have the same number of rows as Matrix A has columns.</p>"
            . "<p> What size matrices would you like? </p>";
         echo "  <form method='POST' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' onsubmit='return param_check_mux();'>                                            
                     <p>A Rows:<input type='text' name='arows' id='arows'> A Columns:<input type='text' name='acolumns' id='acolumns'></p>
                     <p>B Rows:<input type='text' name='brows' id='brows'> B Columns:<input type='text' name='bcolumns' id='bcolumns'></p>
                     <input type='submit' value='Compile my Matrices!' name='submit'>                            
                 </form>";
    break;
?>
```

So basically, if a user was to enter in 'A Rows' the number '3', I want 'B Columns' to auto populate and also hold a '3' value.  I wish this to work the other way also, so if 'B Columns' = '3' then 'A Rows' would = '3' also.

I can't seem to find a correct example online anywhere, or rather, I do not know how to word the question in the search as it is quite specific.

Appreciate any help in advance.  Thank you.

Comment: The way is to use JavaScript. A way to begin: [CodeAcademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this would would grab the values using javascript. I tried to keep the example fairly basic so you can have a good understanding of how to pull and fill values using JavaScript.

```js
function fillB(){
 var anum = document.getElementById('aRow').value;
  var bnum = document.getElementById('bRow');
  bnum.value = anum;
}

function fillA(){
 var bnum = document.getElementById('bRow').value;
  var anum = document.getElementById('aRow');
  anum.value = bnum;
}
```

```html
A: <input type="number" onblur="fillB()" id="aRow">
B: <input type="number" onblur="fillA()" id="bRow">
```

Comment: Thank you for the example code, very easy to read and understand!

This worked a treat, appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    // Set the B Columns if A rows changed
    jQuery('#arows').on('change', function()
    {
        jQuery('#bcolumns').val(jQuery('#arows').val());
    });

    // Set the A rows if B Columns changed
    jQuery('#bcolumns').on('change', function()
    {
        jQuery('#arows').val(jQuery('#bcolumns').val());
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try and  use Javascript on the client side. You listen for changes in input value and then take the appropriate actions. Example :

```
<body>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <div> Matrix A  <br/> 
            <label> Rows </label><input type='text' name='arows' id='arows'></input>
            <label> Columns </label> <input type='text' name='acolumns' id='acolumns' onchange=columnChange(this.value)></input>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div>  Matrix B <br/> 
            <label> Rows </label> <input type='text' name='brows' id='brows' onchange=rowChange(this.value)></input>
            <label> Columns </label> <input type='text' name='bcolumns' id='bcolumns'>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function columnChange(input){ 
            document.getElementById("brows").value=input;
        } 
        function rowChange(input){ 
            document.getElementById("acolumns").value=input;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```